# Change order of SVG elements using javascript

Tags: javascript, svg

I have an SVG in an HTML doc and would like to make it so that when I click on a rectangle it moves to the top layer. The only thing I found for this was this:

`return this.parent.removeElement(this).put(this);`

but this doesn't work.

Comment: Can you show your code?

Answer (score 1):

You want [insertBefore](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.insertBefore) or [appendChild](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.appendChild) instead of removeElement and put

both insertBefore/appendChild remove the element from where it was when they put somewhere else.